# Wrong reference using \input twice for the same file

Tags: cross-referencing, input

I have a short piece of text with an image that I need to use more than once in my document. The rational solution I came up with is to put the text in a file and call the file when needed, something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\input{test}

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1]
\input{test}

\end{document}
```

where in the file `test.tex` there is the reusable piece:

```
The image id is: \ref{image}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{randomimage}
\caption{A random caption.}
\label{image}
\end{figure}
```

Problem is: the first `\ref` is wrong, as can be seen in the following image:

[image: The wrong ref]

Now, I know this could be solved copying and pasting the text any time I need it... but it has obvious shortcomings and I would like to avoid it

Comment: Do you _really_ want to include an identical image and caption but with different numbers each time? Copy and paste would have the same result as using `\input`. the point is you have used the same label for different figures and that is an error (for which you will get a warning in the log file)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I figured that it was a problem of labels; I need to put it twice (three times maybe) exactly in the same way, and given that I will have to modify it a LOT in the next weeks, I figured that using \input I would have save time and possible errors...

Comment: You have the same label defined multiple times: you have to supply a fresh one or generate a different one for each input. So it depends whether you need to reference the pictures or not in the text.

Comment: @egreg Yep I need to reference it... I sense that you are suggesting the copy and paste methodology :D

Comment: @scannerdarkly Not at all. I was thinking to something like David's answer, and the information was needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give a different label to each instance. The easiest way is to use a macro rather than an input file and supply a symbolic name each time:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand\fig[1]{%
The image id is: \ref{#1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[viewport=0 0 100 100]{randomimage}
\caption{A random caption.}
\label{#1}
\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\fig{test}

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1]
\fig{test2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a macro prefix before the label name that is redefined for each `\input`.
The file `test.tex` with the image. It uses `\prefix image` as label name. If `\prefix` is not defined, the label remains `image`.

```
\providecommand*{\prefix}{}
The image id is: \ref{\prefix image}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{randomimage}
\caption{A random caption.}
\label{\prefix image}
\end{figure}
```

The main file that redefines the prefix. Now the two labels can be referenced as `first:image` and `second:image`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\prefix}{}

\begin{document}

Images \ref{first:image} and \ref{second:image}.

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\renewcommand*{\prefix}{first:}
\input{test}

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1]
\renewcommand*{\prefix}{second:}
\input{test}

\end{document}
```